# coprocessor deployment : replacing jar without restarting hbase will take effect?

Tags: hbase

Let's assume this case.

I have a coprocessor declared in hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
<value>my.co.processor</value>
<property>
```

and in hbase-env.sh I declared coprocessor classpath like this

```
export HBASE_CLASSPATH="${HBASE_HOME}/lib/coprocessor.jar"
```

1. If I find a bug in that coprocessor later, can I just replace that jar file in all region servers without restarting entire hbase?
2. If I want to add another coprocessor, then I think I have to restart entire Hbase, am I correct?
   I know I can declare in hbase shell for every single table, but I think that's not an option to think about if I have many tables to apply new coprocessor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can load the coprocessor to a specific HTable:
hTableDescriptor.addCoprocessor(className, path, Coprocessor.PRIORITY_USER, null);
In this way, you only need to disable the table, add a coprocessor and the enable table.

Comment: Doing this will not reload the class in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the jar files with the same name and use rolling restart to avoid downtime. By this way, all of your jars will be reloaded. But, be careful to have no Exception when your coprocessor classes are loaded; otherwise, you should stop your hbase cluster and copy the corrected jars and start cluster.